# Java increment and assignment operator

Tags: java, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

I am confused about the post ++ and pre ++ operator , for example in the following code

```
int x = 10;
x = x++;

sysout(x);
```

will print 10 ?

It prints 10,but I expected it should print 11

but when I do

```
x = ++x; instead of x = x++;
```

it will print eleven as I expected , so why does x = x++; doesn't change the the value of x ?

Comment: Because of this kind of confusion, you really shouldn't do this in real code.

Comment: Instead of `x = x++` ==> `x++`

Comment: Voting to reopen: the duplicate question is about a specific difference between pre- and post-increment. While understanding that difference would help to answer this question, it is not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, the printout of 10 is correct. The key to understanding the reason behind the result is the difference between pre-increment `++x` and post-increment `x++` compound assignments. When you use pre-increment, the value of the expression is taken after performing the increment. When you use post-increment, though, the value of the expression is taken *before* incrementing, and stored for later use, after the result of incrementing is written back into the variable.

Here is the sequence of events that leads to what you see:

- `x` is assigned `10`
- Because of `++` in post-increment position, the current value of `x` (i.e. `10`) is stored for later use
- New value of `11` is stored into `x`
- The temporary value of `10` is stored back into `x`, writing right over `11` that has been stored there.

Answer (score 6):

**Post Increment(n++)** : First execute the statement then increase the value by one.

**Pre Increment (++n)** : First increase the value by one then execute the statement.

Example:

```
class IncrementTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("***Post increment test***");
        int n = 10;
        System.out.println(n);      // output  10
        System.out.println(n++);    // output  10
        System.out.println(n);      // output  11

        System.out.println("***Pre increment test***");
        int m = 10;
        System.out.println(m);      // output  10
        System.out.println(++m);    // output  11
        System.out.println(m);      // output  11
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I also stumbled by the trickiness of post-increment operator while preparing for a Java certification exam. Most, even the experienced, think post-increment (++) operator increments the variable after the execution of the ***statement***, just as @bartektartanus stated above. This thinking is good enough for most real world coding, but breaks down if a post/pre-incremented/decremented variable occurs more than once within a statement. Looks like the so-called interview/knowledge test questions promptly check for this loose assumption. It is worth breaking this up. The accepted answer above is not so helpful for a concise, logical mnemonic.

```
public class Test {
    static int x = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(x++);
    }

    private static void print(int x) {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(Test.x);
    }
}

Output
10
11
```

Per the common assumption, the static variable x would be incremented after completion of the call to the `print` method. But when checked inside the method, it has already been incremented. So, post- increment, decrement operaters submit the variable value to the method or operator to which they are parameters, and increment/decrement the associated variable immediately before the operator/method gets executed. The pre-increment/decrement operation is somewhat less confusing, but again even this happens per method or operator, not the whole statement.

```
// The OP
int x = 10;
x = x++; // x = 10. x does get incremented but before the assignment operation

int x = 10;
x = x++ + x; // x = 21. x got incremented immediately after the addition operator grabbed its value.
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [The Java tutorials - Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html):

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or after (postfix) the operand. The code `result++;` and `++result;` will both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is that the prefix version (`++result`) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix version (`result++`) evaluates to the original value. If you are just performing a simple increment/decrement, it doesn't really matter which version you choose. But if you use this operator in part of a larger expression, the one that you choose may make a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a reference in JLS, so this answer is predicated on the speculation that you are **not** invoking undefined behavior, because this is Java.

```
x = x++; // Assign the old value of `x` to x, before increment.
x = ++x; // Assign the new value of `x` to x, after increment.
```

This is the based on the definition of postfix and prefix operators.

Answer (score -1):

When you do this:

```
x = x++;
```

It actually is translated to "Assign 'x' to 'x' and then increment 'x' by one".

Whereas in this case:

```
x = ++x;
```

It gets translated to "Increment 'x' by one, then assign it to 'x'".

Comment: It seems it is the case, removed precedence talk.