# Java Incremental Oddity

Tags: java, post-increment

You may have already seen this somewhere, but I couldn't find a question on it.  It's just a curiosity but I want to know what exactly is happening under the hood:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   j = j++;
}

System.out.println(j);
```

The output of above will be 0, despite first appearances. Previously, I thought it would work as follows: `j` on the right (0) is assigned to `j` on the left (0), then `j` on the left is incremented to 1.  My question is: since `j` on the left is at the same address as `j` on the right, why doesn't the increment stick afterwards?  I had thought before that the post-incremental operator delayed execution until after the assignment.  Like how this: "`j = 0; k = j++;`" will result in `k == 0` and `j == 1`.  So exactly what happens with the compiler when it's executing "`j = j++;`"?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java (and then in your head evaluate `j++` to zero, increment `j` and then assign zero to `j` and there you go)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java increment and assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564603/java-increment-and-assignment-operator)

Comment: Thanks sfiss, I didn't see that post.  The third answer down in that post answers it; that the post-increment operator actually executes just *prior* to assignment, not after the entire statement has executed, as I had thought before.

Comment: To anyone reading this question, please do NOT down vote it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial:

since ++ is a suffix, it means the increment happens after the assignment.

So in this case you:

1. assign j = j which leaves j at 0
2. increment the right hand side j,

but this doesn't affect the new j since it happens after the assignment.

This would be similar to

```
int newj = oldj;
oldj = oldj+1;
```

Comment: That similarity is not exact; j's address never changes and if the value at that address is incremented after the assignment, then it would still go from 0-100; that was kind of my point in asking about what the compiler does exactly.  But I see from a link in another question now that it actually submits the original value to the operator and executes the increment just PRIOR to assignment.  Sorry if my wording caused any confusion.

Comment: To see what exactly happens, it is best to decompile to bytecode and check foryourself. That is a very interesting exercise to do