# How does "num" become changed in this boolean so that it becomes 6?

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic

```
int num = 5;
if (num != 5 & num++ != 6 | (num = num--) == 6)
System.out.println("true " + num);
else
System.out.println("false " + num);
```

The output of this code is "true, 6". I need help on understanding how num evaluates to the number 6 through the boolean statement.

Comment: Why do people specifically look for fringe cases that no reasonable coder would use. Using the pre- and post-decrement operators in the middle of an expression is just asking for trouble, and it may not be portable to another compiler.

Comment: @NomadMaker: Because this is the kind of trickery that professors or certifiers can put on tests.  Which is why I'll never be a certified Java developer.

Comment: My point is that this is the sort of thing that should not be on tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Colin here has put, there is actually a lot going on here!

Let me take one half of the expression in the if condition first;

```
    num != 5 & num++ != 6
```

Now what this does is first evaluates that num is not equal to 5 ,ie, false

Second, evaluates that num is not equal to 6 ,ie, true (postincrement)

Third, evaluates for the bitwise AND operator ,ie, false & true

**Making the result `false` for this half of the expression**

Forth, increments the value of num ,ie, from 5 to 6



Now for the remaining expression;

```
    (num = num--) == 6
```

This part of the expression first evaluates the bracket.

Here num-- decrements num and returns the old value which is 6 currently.
Then this value is assigned to num again it's a classic postincrement/assignment confusion (Do see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564625/11226302 for detailed explanation)

Second, it evaluates if num is equal to `6` ,ie, `true`

That is how the value of num evaluates to `6` at the end of the expression.

**This makes the second half of the expression `true`**

After this the `|` bitwise inclusive OR operator takes precedence and evaluates the overall expression, which is

```
    false | true
```

Making it `true`.